# Lebesgue point and integration

Tags: integration, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

Let $f$ be in $L^1_{\text{loc}}(\mathbb{R})$. We know that for almost every $t$
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{1}{h} \int_t^{t+h} |f(u)-f(t)|\text{d} u = 0.
$$
My question is : can we say that for almost every $s$
$$ 
\lim_{h\to 0} \int_0^s \frac{1}{h} \int_t^{t+h} |f(u)-f(t)|\text{d} u \text{d} t = 0 ?
$$
The quantity inside the integral (between $0$ and $s$) goes to $0$ but I can't find a bound independent of $h$ to apply dominated convergence.

Comment: Your first equation is true for _every_ $t$, isn't it? (And "almost every $s$" makes no sense for your second equation, because it's about intervals $(0,s)$.)

Comment: @TonyK The first equation is true only for the Lebesgue points of $f$, so no the first equation isn't true for every $t$. For the second equation, $s$ belongs to $\mathbb{R}$, so my "almost every" $s$ means that for almost every $s$ with respect to the Lebesgue measure on $\mathbb{R}$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $h_{n}\downarrow0$ and define
$$
f_{n}:\left[0,s\right]\to\mathbb{R},t\mapsto\frac{1}{h_{n}}\int_{t}^{t+h_{n}}\left|f\left(u\right)-f\left(t\right)\right|\,{\rm d}u.
$$
By the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, $f_{n}\left(t\right)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0$
for almost all $t\in\left[0,s\right]$. Furthermore,
$$
0\leq f_{n}\left(t\right)\leq\frac{1}{h_{n}}\cdot\int_{t}^{t+h_{n}}\left|f\left(u\right)\right|\,{\rm d}u+\frac{1}{h_{n}}\int_{t}^{t+h_{n}}\left|f\left(t\right)\right|\,{\rm d}u=\frac{1}{h_{n}}\int_{t}^{t+h_{n}}\left|f\left(u\right)\right|\,{\rm d}u+\left|f\left(t\right)\right|=:g_{n}\left(t\right).
$$
Again, by the Lebesgue differentiation theorem, $g_{n}\left(t\right)\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}2\left|f\left(t\right)\right|$
for almost all $t\in\left[0,s\right]$.

Finally,
\begin{eqnarray*}
\int_{0}^{s}g_{n}\left(t\right)\,{\rm d}t & = & \int_{0}^{s}\left|f\left(t\right)\right|\,{\rm d}t+\frac{1}{h_{n}}\int_{0}^{s}\int_{t}^{t+h_{n}}\left|f\left(u\right)\right|\,{\rm d}u\,{\rm d}t\\
 & \overset{\text{Fubini}}{=} & \int_{0}^{s}\left|f\left(t\right)\right|\,{\rm d}t+\frac{1}{h_{n}}\int_{0}^{s+h_{n}}\int_{\max\{0, u-h_{n}\}}^{\min\{u,s\}}\left|f\left(u\right)\right|\,{\rm d}t\,{\rm d}u\\
 & = & \int_{0}^{s}\left|f\left(t\right)\right|\,{\rm d}t+\int_{0}^{s+h_{n}} \frac{\min\{u,s\} - \max\{0, u-h_{n}\}}{h_n} \cdot\left|f\left(u\right)\right|\,{\rm d}u\\
 & \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} & 2\int_{0}^{s}\left|f\left(t\right)\right|\,{\rm d}t=\int_{0}^{s}\lim_{n\to\infty}g_{n}\left(t\right)\,{\rm d}t.
\end{eqnarray*}
Hence, by a special version of the dominated convergence theorem (see
[General Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72174/general-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem)),
we conclude
$$
\int_{0}^{s}f_{n}\left(t\right)\,{\rm d}t\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}0.
$$

EDIT: In the last step above, we used (for $n$ large enough):
\begin{eqnarray*}
 &  & \int_{0}^{s+h_{n}}\frac{\min\left\{ u,s\right\} -\max\left\{ 0,u-h_{n}\right\} }{h_{n}}\left|f\left(u\right)\right|\,{\rm d}u\\
 & = & \int_{h_{n}}^{s}\underbrace{\frac{u-\left(u-h_{n}\right)}{h_{n}}}_{=1}\left|f\left(u\right)\right|\,{\rm d}u+\int_{0}^{h_{n}}\underbrace{\frac{u-0}{h_{n}}}_{\in\left[0,1\right]}\left|f\left(u\right)\right|\,{\rm d}u+\int_{s}^{s+h_{n}}\underbrace{\frac{s-\left(u-h_{n}\right)}{h_{n}}}_{\in\left[0,1\right]}\cdot\left|f\left(u\right)\right|\,{\rm d}u\\
 & \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{\text{dominated convergence (e.g.)}} & \int_{0}^{s}\left|f\left(u\right)\right|\,{\rm d}u
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I think that the change of variable, change the integral between $0$ and $s$ and the integral between $t$ and $t+h_n$ into an integral between $h_n$ to $s+h_n$ and an integral between $u-h_n$ and $u$, right? Otherwise, it is perfect. Thanks.

Comment: I am not sure that this is correct. For example in the first line, if $t = 0$, then $u$ ranges from $[t, t+h_n] = [0,h_n]$ and if $t = s$, then $u$ ranges from $[t,t+h_n] = [s,s+h_n]$. So all in all, $u$ can range from $0$ to $s+h_n$. What you do here is (e.g.) to reformulate the integral boundaries as characteristic functions, i.e. $\int_{u-h_n}^u ... \, dt= \int \chi_{[u-h_n, u]}(t) \, dt$. Then use Fubini and compute the new boundaries from the characteristic functions.

Comment: Your domain $\{ 0\le u \le s+h_n, u-h_n\le t \le u \}$ contains the point $(0,-h_n)$ that doesn't belong to $\{ 0 \le t \le s, t \le u \le t+h_n \}$, right?

Comment: Okay, I adapted my post, I hope it is correct now. The last step (where the convergence is claimed) now requires a bit more thought, but is not too hard to see. Thanks for the correction.