# Stronger version of the dominated convergence theorem

Tags: real-analysis

Let $g$, $\{g_n\}$ be integrable and $f$, $\{f_n\}$ be measurable. Suppose $\mid{f_n}\mid\le{g_n}$ and $f_n\to f \ a.e$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int{g_n}=\int g$. Show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int | f_n-f| =0$.

I will use dominated convergence theorem. But I can't find the dominating function.

Comment: You could have used a better title like "Variant of the dominated convergence theorem".

Comment: And I think you some more requirements, something like $g_n \to g$ a.e.

Comment: If you add the requirement $g_n \to g$ ae., then you can find an answer here http://math.stackexchange.com/q/72174/27978.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is false (as @Alex S suggested). Working on $\mathbb {R}$ with Lebesgue measure, set $f_n=g_n = \chi_{[n,n+1]}.$ Then $f_n \to 0$ everywhere, and $\int g_n \to \int \chi_{[0,1]}.$ But clearly $f_n$ does not convverge to $0$ in $L^1.$

Let's add the hypothesis that $g_n \to g$ a.e. Then hint: Apply Fatou's Lemma to $g+g_n -|f-f_n|.$

Comment: Yes! if this condition add, i solve this problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Let $f_n = 1_{[n,n+1]}, f = 0$, $g_n = f_n$ and $g=1_{[0,1]}$, then we have
$f_n(x) \to f(x)$ everywhere, $|f_n| \le g_n$, $\int g_n = \int g$, but
$\int |f_n-f| = 1$ for all $n$.

Comment: Thank you! i know that this problem needs more requirement.