# I am having trouble solving this problem from the book " Measure Theory" by Donald L.Cohn.

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(X,\mathcal A ,\mu)$  be a measure space and let $f$ and $f_1 ,f_2 ,....$ be non-negative functions that belong to $\mathcal L^1(X,\mathcal A,\mu,\mathbb R)$ and satisfy- 
 (i) $\{f_n\}$ converges to $f$ almost everywhere. 
 (ii) $\int f\ d\mu=\lim_n \int f_n\ d\mu$. 
 Show that $\lim_n \int |f_n-f|\ d\mu=0$ .

Comment: What does it mean to say "$(X,\mathcal A,\mu,\mathbb R)$" is a measure space?

Comment: I tried to consider the case by dropping the "Almost everywhere" condition and replacing it by "Everywhere". But have no clue how to proceed further.

Comment: Yes its a measure space  , where $\mathcal A$ is the sigma algebra and $\mu$ is the measure. Oops that $\mathbb R$ is unceccesary. Sorry

Comment: This question has been already asked for several times...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First note that since 
$$
|f_n -f| \leq |f_n| + |f|
$$
then $|f_n -f| \in L^1$. Also by *(i)* we have that $ |f_n| + |f| \to 2|f|$ almost everywhere. Hence hypothesis *(ii)* gives that 
$$
\int |f_n| + |f| d\mu \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow} \int 2|f| d\mu
$$
Again *(i)* gives that $|f-f_n| \to 0 $ almost everywhere, thus by a [generalized version of the dominated convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72174/general-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem) we have in fact that
$$
\int |f_n - f|d\mu \underset{n \to \infty}{\longrightarrow}0
$$

Comment: Thank you so much. This is what I was looking for .

Comment: You are welcome @LavKumar ! I am glad I could help !

Answer (score 0):

This is a particular version of one of the lemmas of Riesz:

> Suppose that $1\leqslant p <\infty$ and that $f_n\to f$ a.e. Then the following are equivalent:
>
> $(1)$ Convergence of norms: $\lVert f_n\rVert_p\to \lVert f\rVert_p$
>
> $(2)$ $L^p$-convergence: $\lVert f-f_n\rVert_p\to 0$.

*Proof* One direction follows from the triangle inequality. For the converse, recall that $g_n=2^{p-1}(|f|^p+|f_n|^p)-|f-f_n|^p\geqslant 0$, so by the lemma of Fatou $$2^p \int |f|^p= \int \liminf\; g_n\leqslant \liminf\; 2^{p-1}\int (|f|^p+|f_n|^p)-\limsup\; \lVert f-f_n\rVert^p$$

Which gives $\limsup \lVert f-f_n\rVert \leqslant 0$, as desired.

*Note* The lemma fails for $p=\infty$!