# Characterization of the $L^p$ convergence.

Tags: real-analysis

If $\mu$ is a positive measure on a measurable space $(X,\mu )$ and $f, f_n \in L^p(\mu )$ for $1<p<\infty$, are such that $f_n \rightarrow f$ pointwise a.e., show that $||f_n-f||_p\rightarrow 0$ if and only if $||f_n||_p\rightarrow ||f||_p$.

I think that for the nontrivial implication, one approach could be to show somehow that $f_n$ converges weakly to $f$ and then using the reflexivity of the space and the boundedness of the sequence to conclude. But is $L^p$ reflexive for an arbitrary measure $\mu$, or it has to be $\sigma$-finite? Also is there a more elementary solution, probably using the Vitaly convergence theorem or things like that?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/51502/convergence-a-e-and-of-norms-implies-that-in-lebesgue-space) for one approach.

Comment: see Corollary 7.15
https://www.math.ucdavis.edu/~hunter/measure_theory/measure_notes_ch7.pdf for that $L^p$ is reflexive  for $1<p<\infty$ for arbitrary measure space, and for $p=1$ it is reflexive if the space is $\sigma$ finite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[*Generalized* Lebesgue dominated convergence theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72174/general-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem) works pretty well here. If we notice that
$$
\underbrace{|f_n-f|^p}_{F_n}\le \underbrace{2^p(|f_n|^p+|f|^p)}_{G_n}
$$
so a.e. $|F_n|\le G_n$, $F_n\to 0$, $G_n\to 2^{p+1}|f|^p=G\in L^1$ and $\int G_n\to \int G$. Thus $\|F_n\|_1\to 0$.

Comment: I didn't know that the proof of this theorem is so simple by using the Generalized LDCT

Comment: @A.G. Perfect! So we don't even need that p>1. I was misled by this assumption and think we somewhere need reflexivity. Thank you very much!