# Weierstrass M-test and DCT/general DCT - relationship?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence

The $M$ in the [WMT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) looks like the $g$ in [DCT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dominated_convergence_theorem)/[General](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72174/general-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem) DCT. Is there some relationship such as

$$g_n = \sum_{k=1}^{n} M_k$$ ?

Comment: They play similar roles in the proofs but since the theorems hypothesise and conclude about different convergence modes ($L^1$ vs $L^\infty$), the analogy doesn't help much in practice.

Comment: @MaxFreiburghaus thanks! Post as answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They play similar roles in the proofs but since the theorems make conclusions about different convergence modes ($L^1$-convergence vs uniform convergence), the analogy doesn't help much in practice.