# Does pointwise convergence plus convergence of $\int |f_n| $ imply convergence of $\int f_n$?

Tags: integration, lebesgue-integral, pointwise-convergence

I am sure the answer to this question is already somewhere here, but I could not find it.

If we have a sequence of functions $f_n \in L_1$, with pointwise limit $f$, and assuming we know that $\int |f_n| d\mu \rightarrow \int |f| d\mu$, where the latter might possibly be infinite, does this imply $\int f_n d\mu \rightarrow \int f d\mu$?

The reason I am asking this is because I was confused if I could apply monotone convergence in the case that I do not have monotonicity of the functions itself but rather of the absolute values, i.e. $|f_n|\leq |f_{n+1}|$? And if not, is there a good counterexample that illustrates how this approach will fail?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF $|f|=\infty$ the answer may be no. For example
$$f_n(x)=\sum^n_{j=1}(-1)^j j\mathbb{1}_{(j,j+1]}(x)$$
$f_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f:=\sum^\infty_{j=1}(-1)^j j\mathbb{1}_{(j,j+1]}(x)$, $\lim_n\int |f_n|=\infty=\int|f|$, and
$\lim_n\int|f-f_n|=\infty$.

When $f\in L_1$, the answer is yes and it follows from the following version of dominated convergence

> If $f_n\in L_1$, $g_n\in L_1$, $f_n\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}f$ $\mu$-almost surely, $|f_n|\leq g_n$, and $\lim_n\int g_n=\int\lim_n g_n$, then
> $$\int|f-f_n|d\mu\xrightarrow{n\rightarrow\infty}0$$
> In particular $\lim_n\int f_n\,d\mu=\int f\,d\mu$.

by setting $g_n=|f_n|$.

---

Edit: For a discussion of the version of dominated convergence I quoted above you may see [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/72174/121671).

Answer (score 1):

I believe [Scheffé's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scheff%C3%A9%27s_lemma) answer's your question affirmatively. It says that if $f_n \to f$ a.e. where $f_n, f\in L^1$ then
$$ \int |f_n -f|d\mu \to 0 \iff \int |f_n|d\mu \to \int |f|d\mu$$

Comment: Minor quibble: under OP's assumptions, it might happen that $f \notin L^1$. For example, consider $\mathbb{N}$ with the counting measure, and take $f(k) = (-1)^k$ and
$$ f_n(k) = \begin{cases} (-1)^k,&\text{if $k \leq n$};\\ 0,&\text{otherwise}. \end{cases} $$

Comment: @JossevanDobbendeBruyn Good point thank you for mentioning that!

Comment: @Oliver Diaz thanks for the counterexample! If you would make this an answer, I would accept it (since it also shows how the mentioned application of monotone convergence could fail). (but @E G , this answer is of course also very helpful)

Comment: @a_student: I'm glad you found my comment helpful. I just posted it as an answer at your request.

Comment: Another remark.  In the OP could it happen that $f_n \to f$ a.e. and $\int |f_n|$ converges, but not to $\int |f|$ ??