# I have a problem with showing the indirect implication

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Let $(E,A,\mu)$ be a measure space
And let $(f_n)_{n \in IN}$ be a sequence of integrable functions that converges to an integrable function f.

Show that :

$\int\lvert f_n - f \lvert d\mu$ $\to$ 0 $\Leftrightarrow$ $\int \lvert f_n \lvert d\mu \to \int \lvert f \lvert d\mu$

(The integrals are over E)

Comment: One direction follows from Lipschitzness of $|\cdot|$. You need to show some work, or do a slightly better search or your question will get closed.

Comment: Yes I know , one implication is clear... , but the other one are very complicated.

Comment: Maybe look up the generalised dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: It is not obvious, but not very complicated.

Comment: There is an other way too : If  $\{f_n / n \in IN\}$ is an equi-integrable set, then there is a way to the proof

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/72174/27978

Comment: Thank you .