# Need a control function

Tags: lebesgue-integral

Let $\{f_n\}$ be a sequence of measurable functions on measurable $E$ that converge pointwise a.e. on $E$ to $f$.

Let $\{g_n\}$ be a sequence of **measurable functions** on $E$ that converge pointwise a.e. on $E$ to $g$ such that $|f_n| \leq g_n$ for all $n \geq 1$

Knowing that $\lim\limits_{n \rightarrow \infty}$ $\int_E$ $g_n$ = $\int_E$ $g < \infty$, (so $g$ is $a.e.$ finite), how can I build a **control integrable**

**function** for all $f_n$ fo be able to apply DCT.

I doubt I can claim that there exists $N>0$ such that $|f_n| \leq g$ for all $n \geq N$, or can I?

Comment: You won't be able to construct such a function. For a proof of the statement, see [General Lebesgue Dominated Convergence Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/72174/general-lebesgue-dominated-convergence-theorem)

Comment: @nicoyanovsky Thank you. I am familiar with the general proof using Fatou's Lemma. I think that the goal of the exercise is to train on how to develop a control function from a sequence of "measurable" functions.

Comment: I don't think there's a way to do that for general sequences $f_n$ and $g_n$. If you want an explicit way to construct the dominant function you might need some more information about the $f_n$ and $g_n$

Comment: @nicoyanovsky that's what I thought. All the info regarding $f_n$ and $g_n$ were included in the question.